# Chromecast displays weird artifacts in my custom receiver web app

Tags: javascript, html, css, chromecast

So I built a Chromecast receiver -- which is just a web app that can communicate with another device.

When I display it on the cc it sometimes puts a dark tint over the picture with weird boxes of no tint around my elements. The element margins are far smaller than those clear boxes. In fact, there are no elements that have margins or padding that looks like these clear boxes.

This only happens on Chromecast. On my chrome browser it doesn't happen. I use Materializecss as my stylesheet if that matters.

[image]

Comment: You can connect your chrome debugger to your chromecast and when that happens, inspect elements to see what is happening.

Comment: using the debugger I still cannot find any element that matches up with these weird boxes.